# elixir command line '-pa' options

Tags: elixir

I'm looking at Elixir code in a project where the start-up script is:

```
elixir -pa _build/<a directory with .beam files> -S  mix run -e "MyApp" --no-deps-check --no-compile --no-halt
```

I'm curious what the `-pa` flag option.  I couldn't find a man page or help page for elixir.

```
$ man elixir
No manual entry for elixir
```

Is there online documentation for other command-line options for elixir?

Answer (score 5):

Run `elixir --help` instead of `man elixir` (a man page for Elixir should come sooner rather than later, see [this pull request](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/pull/3043)). The output says:

```
...
-pa "path"        Prepends the given path to Erlang code path (*)
...
```

where the `*` at  the end signals that this option can be passed more than once.